Passing photoauostic audible messages via mid-infrared lasers can be done. Can we achieve this with a microwave?
In medicine, Photoauostic spectrography is used in non invansive glucose monitoring. To acheive this, we use invisible laser (Mid-Infrared) range in electromagnatic spectrum.
The photoacoustic effect work when acoustic waves are generated as a result of light incidence on a material with specific properties. In this case, airborne water vapor to absorb light and generate sound. Because there is almost always a little water in the air, especially around people, the effect can work even in relatively dry conditions.
Can we use RF (Radio / microwave) to produce photoauostic alert audible message which can be hear with normal ears (without a special any device) from sattellite or local radio transmitter in the country ?
If this can be done with microwave, then we can use this to alert Tsunami and other natural disasters to the people :-)

So, there are these things called loudspeakers, widely used worldwide, that translate electrical signals to audio waves perceptible by people. Now seriously though, you just described a loudspeaker. It would not be different. Secondly, for an EM signal to be converted and loud enough it means it needs to be losing energy to the environment: as you mentioned, eg absorbed by water. Sound waves, I imagine, are less lossy, and there is not the need to invest in new infrastructure. Thirdly, if radio waves were already audible, why don't we hear them? Satellite and radio works because its not (1/2)

(2/2) absorbed by air: they work typically in transparency windows, or if needed, as in high speed internet, repeaters are used. Using something that would induce sound from EM, and with the objective of long distance usage means anyone close to the emitter would find it extremely extremely loud (it already happens with speakers, but I imagine it would be way way worse with the way you described it)
